# Why is it not possible to declare a function with VAR return type?

Tags: function, c#-4.0, dynamic-data, return-value, return-type

In C#, we have `var` data type but we can't use  it as functions return type.
Why this is not possible?

```
public var myFunction()
{
    var = some operations
}
```

Comment: Well, if you dont know, how must the compiler know?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe it's partly due to the design of the compiler. Eric Lippert [blogged](https://ericlippert.com/2009/01/26/why-no-var-on-fields/) about why *fields* can't use implicit typing, and I suspect some of the same arguments hold for methods.

But you could easily end up with ambiguity anyway. For example:

```
var Method1(bool callMethod2)
{
    return callMethod2 ? Method2() : null;
}

var Method2()
{
    return Method1(false);
}
```

What should the type be here?

A simpler example:

```
var Method1(bool throwException)
{
    if (!throwException)
    {
        return Method1(true);
    }
    throw new Exception("Bang!");
}
```

Admittedly this sort of ambiguity could simply be disallowed, but I *suspect* that the design team felt that the added complexity of both design and implementation wasn't worth the benefit. Don't forget that they're running with limited resources - given a choice between `var` for methods and `async/await`, I'd pick the latter in a heartbeat. (Admittedly there are other features I'd have picked instead of `dynamic`, but that's a different matter...)

Note that return type inference *is* performed for lambda expressions, so the very idea of it isn't crazy. For example:

```
IEnumerable<string> x = new[] { "x", "y", "z" };

var result = x.Select(s => { return s.Length; }); // Long form
```

There the compiler infers the complete type of the lambda expression when it performs overload resolution on `Select`, converting it to a `Func<string, int>`. It's not inconceivable to apply the same ideas to methods - just complicated.

Comment: Your analysis is, as usual, spot on. Doing this feature right requires *whole program analysis*, which has major architectural and performance impacts on the compiler. Also, all the reasons for "no var on fields" apply. For example, that we don't have a standardized way to represent an anonymous type in a public API.  If you want a language that affords this sort of type inference, try F#.

Answer (score 2):

`var` is NOT a datatype in C#. That's why you cannot use it as a return parameter. The compiler infers the type at compile time from the right handside of the assignment and bearing in mind that it is known at compile time you need to use the real type as return value. In C# 4.0 you could use the [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx) type:

```
public dynamic myFunction()
{
    var = some operations
}
```

Comment: -1, because what's being proposed is simply that the compiler should infer what the real return type is... making a declaration which uses `var` equivalent to the same method declaration with an explicit return type, inferred from the return statements within the method body. It's not inconceivable - just complicated. Note that it's already done for lambda expressions, as per the example in my answer.