# Is there is any way to use 'var' keyword against function Parameter?

Tags: c#

I was studying Generics in C#. I Think my  question (..that I'm going to ask) may be stupid but someone says that "Question Everything".

So i was thinking little a while ago...

**Why we can't use 'var' keyword in function parameter list?**

**For Example:**

[image]

Dynamic Keyword is working...

[image]

Comment: The short answer: Because the language specification says so

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it not possible to declare a function with VAR return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4132289/why-is-it-not-possible-to-declare-a-function-with-var-return-type)

Comment: You could use `var`only if the compiler can find the right type at compile time. The `T` in the generic is a type and you difine in the bracket (`<>`) the type to use for the parameter or the return value.

Comment: var is a generic variable type but you cannot use it in as a parameter nor a return type.  Instead use object.

Comment: `dynamic` isn't really related to `var`.  I suggest you just read up on these keywords a bit more from the standard documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the var in C# is very different from the var in other languages.

It is important to understand that the var keyword does not mean "variant" and does not indicate that the variable is loosely typed, or late-bound. It just means that the compiler determines and assigns the most appropriate type.

You cannot assign a var variable with null because in that case compiler will not be able to understand the type.

Similarly if you will not be able to return VAR from a method or will not be able to declare method parameter as Var because C# compiler will not be able to define the type of these things at compile time.

Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/implicitly-typed-local-variables

Answer (score 2):

`var` has nothing to do with generics.  It has two uses:

First is to declare an instance of an [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types).  Since it is anonymous, `var` is the only way to declare the variable.

Second is as a shortcut.  It saves you the effort to write the name of the type you need to declare.  However, the compiler must be able to determine the type from the value you assign to your variable.

See more in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/var).

Comment: You can declare anonymous type variables as `object` (since they implicitly derive it) - `var` is not the only way

Comment: @UnholySheep yes, but then you lose access to all the members defined in the anonymous type, thus mostly defeating the purpose.